# Does dot(.) in project name cause "No owin.Enviroment" error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

After almost two hours struggling with `No owin.Environment` error, I am now wondering if the dot `.` in the project name causes the error.

My project name is `XXX.Web`.

In my `Startup.cs`, there is attribute

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WVCCIS.Web.Startup))]
```

In the `Web.Config`, I added

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="XXX.Web.Startup, XXX.Web" />
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup " value="false" />
```

It works fine in VS2013 IIS Express, even without the `appSettings` keys added. But I have never figured out why it failed in the production site, hosed on an IIS7.

The error message is: `No owin.Environment item was found in the context.`

I found in the article [login crashes - no owin.Environment](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792583/new-webform-app-login-crashes-no-owin-environment)

Some comment says,

```
 I can reproduce this bug with MVC5 project by changing namespace to one which contains dots. For example WebApplication1 works, Company.ABC.WebApplication1 doesn't.
```

If that is the case, how can I fix it for some project name that contains a dot? How come it works when debugging in VS, but failed in the production site?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: 4 projects working here, one named `NacionalSoft.Arkan.Web.Mvc5`. Owin class named `NacionalSoft.Arkan.Web.Mvc5.OwinConfig`, Owin config method named `ArkanOwinConfig` and added: `[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(NacionalSoft.Arkan.Web.Mvc5.OwinConfig), "ArkanOwinConfig")]` with no issues at all.